# How does the order-statistic tree look like in Largest Rectangle in a Histogram problem

Tags: algorithm

In http://blog.csdn.net/arbuckle/archive/2006/05/06/710988.aspx, it was mentioned several methods to solve the Largest Rectangle in a Histogram problem. But I do not see how the first method, order-statistic tree, can be used to solve this problem. Could anyone please give a concrete example of this method, i.e. how the tree looks like for an example, let’s say, [7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3]?

Comment: I'd really love to answer your question, but I don't know what the "largest rectangle in a histogram" question is.  Can you provide a link to the description of the inputs and expected output?  Or give your own description. ?

Comment: @templatetypedef: http://www.spoj.pl/problems/HISTOGRA/ is the link. BTW, the example i was trying to use is [7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 3, 3]. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to tell us what this largest rectangle is used for ?

Comment: @Alexandre C.: this isn't about the practicality of this specific problem. It is about how to cleverly design some algorithm to do this fast. Think of it as an intellectual challenge. Just like solving a very difficult planar geometry problem. :)

Comment: @Qiang Li: okay. Is this question drawn from a specific programming challenge ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245/puzzle-find-largest-rectangle-maximal-rectangle-problem