# Get A1Notation of rectangle areas on spreadsheet

Tags: algorithm, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get A1Notation of rectangle areas on spreadsheet. Sample of rectangle on spreadsheet is below image.

[image]

I want to get A1Notation of cells of value "1". I don't want to get "B2, C2, D2, B3, C3, D3, B4, C4, D4". I want to get "B2:D4". My tried script is

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
    if (data[i][j] == 1) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).getA1Notation();
      result.push(range);
    }
  }
}
Logger.log(result);
```

This script returns "B2, C2, D2, B3, C3, D3, B4, C4, D4". `sheet.getDataRange().getA1Notation()` is "A1:D4". Positions of cells of "1" are not always the same. My question is

- When positions of cells of "1" make a rectangle area, are there any ways to retrieve the rectangle area as A1Notation?

  - At sample, I want to get "B2:D4" from spreadsheet or from "B2, C2, D2, B3, C3, D3, B4, C4, D4".

I checked [Puzzle: Find largest rectangle (maximal rectangle problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245/puzzle-find-largest-rectangle-maximal-rectangle-problem) and links. But I cant understand the way to apply this to my script. Thank you so much for your time.

### Edit

These are samples. I get areas in size order.

```
   A B C D E

1  0 0 0 0 0
2  0 1 1 1 0
3  0 1 1 1 0
4  0 1 1 1 0
5  0 0 0 0 0
```

I need "B2:D4".

```
   A B C D E

1  1 1 1 0 0
2  0 1 1 1 0
3  0 1 1 1 0
4  0 1 1 1 0
5  0 0 0 0 0
```

I need "B2:D4" and "A1:C1".

```
   A B C D E

1  0 1 1 1 1
2  0 1 1 1 1
3  0 0 0 1 1
4  0 0 0 0 1
5  0 0 0 0 1
```

I need "B1:E2", "E3:E5", "D3:D3".

Comment: There is not a simple method. If you can be sure that the edges of the table have no gaps, you can use [`Range#getNextDataCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction)) to help find bounding edges, but you still have to implement logic of your own to store the related cell indices and construct the A1 string from them.

Comment: @tehhowch Yes. I think so. But I still cannot find the algorithm to update my script.

Comment: Please add the clarification made on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226192/get-a1notation-of-rectangle-areas-on-spreadsheet#comment87471524_50226600) to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50226600/1595451) and edit the title accordingly.

Comment: @I'-'I I'm sorry for confusing. I updated my answer. If you see unclear, tell me.

Comment: @Rubén I'm sorry for confusing. I updated my answer. If you see unclear, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function as follows :

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
    if (data[i][j] == 1) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).getA1Notation();
      result.push(range);
    }
  }
}
Logger.log(result[0] + ":" + result[result.length-1]);
```

Maybe it's not optimized, because you're iterating over whole data range, but it's hard to tell what the optimized way without knowing your data structure, need in details.

Comment: This is good --- for a single table. If there were a table in `B2:D4`, and another in `G1:J3`, your output would be `G1:D4`

Comment: That why I mentioned `it's hard to tell what the optimized way without knowing your data structure`

Comment: @Umair Thank you for your answer. Sorry. You misunderstand my question. **Positions of cells of "1" are not always the same.** When "B2, C2, D2, B3, C3, D3, B4, C4, D4" and "A1, B1, C1" have "1", your answer returns "A1:D4". But this is not a rectangle area. For example when "A1, B1, C1, B2, C2, D2, B3, C3, D3, B4, C4, D4" have "1", can you update your answer to get a rectangle area and get "B2:D4"?

Comment: When "B2, C2, D2, B3, C3, D3, B4, C4, D4" and "A1, B1, C1", the answer should be 2 areas: "A1:C1" and "B2:D4", or 3 areas "A1", "B1:C4", "D2:D4. @Elsa, your Q is not clear to me.

Comment: Yes @MaxMakhrov you're correct, this is the reason why I couldn't update my answer. :)

Comment: @Max Makhrov I'm sorry for confusing. I commented **When "B2, C2, D2, B3, C3, D3, B4, C4, D4" and "A1, B1, C1" have "1", your answer returns "A1:D4".** I got "A1:D4" from Umair's answer. Actually, I need logic of ``"A1:C1" and "B2:D4"``. I updated my answer. If you see unclear, tell me.

Comment: @Umair I'm sorry for confusing. I commented **When "B2, C2, D2, B3, C3, D3, B4, C4, D4" and "A1, B1, C1" have "1", your answer returns "A1:D4".** I got "A1:D4" from your answer. I updated my answer. If you see unclear, tell me.