# Algorithm for finding grid(s) formed by a list of points

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

**Problem:** Given a list of points on a 2D plane, find all largest grids formed by these points.

A grid, in my definition, is a set of points that "fill a rectangle". Also, there's no need to consider rotated grids in my case.

For example, the points { A, B, C, ... , I } form a grid below:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

But if we remove point E, it's no longer a grid because there's a hole:

```
A B C
D   F
G H I
```

By largest I mean in the following case:

```
A B C
D E F
```

Although the points { A, B, C, D } form a grid, the output should be { A, B, C, D, E, F } because it forms a larger grid.

Finally, grids can overlap, so in this case:

```
A B
C D E
  F G
```

The points {A, B, C, D} and {D, E, F, G} each form a grid.

Context: I want to create a Figma plugin that detects if there are repeated elements, in order to turn them into reusable components. For example in this [Figma design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQkhL.jpg), we can turn each column into a component. This grid problem is a part of the algorithm I'm trying to write.

**What I've tried:**

I first ran the [DBSCAN algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) on the points' x-coordinates and y-coordiantes to find a list of points that align with each other vertically and horizontally respectively, because it allowed for a margin of error when points are not perfectly aligned.

Then I was kind of stuck.

Maybe a way is to loop through each point, treat it as the top-left corner of a potential grid, then search for all possible grid sizes? That sounds pretty inefficient.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245/puzzle-find-largest-rectangle-maximal-rectangle-problem This looks to me like an equivalent case

Comment: This question is not really in the right place in stackoverflow. It is an algorithm problem that should rather be in mathematics or computational-science.